# Symfony Entity on first save

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

In Symfony using doctrine, whats the best way to run a certain function just before an entity is saved/persisted to the database. I only want it to be run once in its lifetime so I guess the construction function is no good.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LifecycleCallback** named `PrePersist` as explained in the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: ahh thanks, I got confused I thought lifetime callbacks were date specific functions only

Answer (score 0):

or

You can either call that function just before the `$em->persist($entity);` function in the controller.

But `PrePersist` is the cleaner way but for testing and small stuff , you can  put before the save function